# iOS 8 UITableViewCell constraints break after adding accessoryType

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, pure-layout

Technically, the constraints don't break but they stop working as intended. I have forked PureLayout's iOS 8 AutoLayout example to replicate this issue. In a nutshell, I have a UITableView with a custom cell that looks like this:

[image]

After adding

```html
self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
```

it looks like this:

[image]

Notice the gap between the title and the body of the cell.

https://github.com/marcus30/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8

Comment: That appears to me to be intended behavior. When using an accessory view the contentView of the cell is reduced by the width of the accessory view. What are you expecting, the text to sit under the accessoryView?

Comment: Yes. A constraint for the body label is set to sit under the title label, with 0 inset.

Comment: ahh I was looking at the horizontal formatting, not the vertical formatting.

Comment: I edited the question to better reflect the issue.

Comment: I don't see this behavior when I set up the cell without using pure-layout.

Comment: @rdelmar do you have an example?

Comment: There's not much to it. I added a label and a text view (with scrolling disabled) to a table view cell. The text view has constraints to the label, and sides and bottom of the cell, the label has one to the top of the cell. There's no code other than 2 IBOutlets in the cell class. The lines to set the estimatedRowHeight and rowHeight for the self-sizing cells were like you have, except I needed to put them in viewDidAppear to make the cell have the correct initial height. There's no need for any calls to updateConstraints or layoutIfNeeded, or anything like that.